# JQuery PHP print image inside Dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page that opens a jQuery dialog like:

```
$( "#editdialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Show photo',
  height: 750,
  width:900,
  modal:true
});


$( ".editer" ).click(function() {
    $( "#editdialog" ).load("photo_view.php");
    $( "#editdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', 'silver');
});
```

The `load_photo.php` code is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT PHOTO FROM USERS WHERE ID='01'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result==FALSE) die("error".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['PHOTO'];
```

If I browse directly to `load_photo.php` the image is shown.
If I load the `load_photo.php` page inside a dialog, the image is not shown.

It can be an error of the `header()` function?

**EDIT**: I add an intermediate page like your suggestions. Now the dialog loads photo_view.php and its code is:

```
 <img src="load_photo.php" width="75" height="75" style="padding:0px;" class="imageborder" onerror="this.src='noimg.jpg'" accept="image/*" />
```

Still not working, same result. In the dialog the img box still remain blank, browsing directly to photo_view.php the image is shown.

Thank you!

Comment: needs to be in an `<img>` tag. Can't dump raw image data directly into the middle of an html document

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it answers your question! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem is that your making an image response (binary) and the browser shows it because it automatically puts it in an `img` tag.

You should remove `header()` and respond with this html code:

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['PHOTO'] . '">';
```